# re.VERBOSE and lookahead assertion error

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a verbose (`re.X`) flagged regex that is throwing an exception, even though it seems to be equivalent to its condensed version.  (I built the former from the latter.)

Condensed version:

```
import re
test = 'catdog'
test2 = 'dogcat'
pat = re.compile(r'(?=\b\w{6}\b)\b\w*cat\w*\b')

print(pat.search(test))
print(pat.search(test2))
# catdog Match object
# dogcat Match object
```

Verbose version:

```
pat = re.compile(r"""(               # Start of group (lookahead); need raw string
                     ?=              # Positive lookahead; notation = `q(?=u)`
                     \b\w{6}\b       # Word boundary and 6 alphanumeric characters
                     )               # End of group (lookahead)
                     \b\w*cat\w*\b   # Literal 'cat' in between 0 or more alphanumeric""", re.X)
print(pat.search(test).string)
print(pat.search(test2).string)

# Throws exception
# error: nothing to repeat at position 83 (line 2, column 22)
```

What's causing this?  I can't find why the expanded version is violating any condition for `re.X`/`re.VERBOSE`.  From docs:

> This flag allows you to write regular expressions that look nicer and
>   are more readable by allowing you to visually separate logical
>   sections of the pattern and add comments. Whitespace within the
>   pattern is ignored, except when in a character class or when preceded
>   by an unescaped backslash. When a line contains a # that is not in a
>   character class and is not preceded by an unescaped backslash, all
>   characters from the leftmost such # through the end of the line are
>   ignored.

There are no character classes or whitespace preceded by unescaped backslashes, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Works fine for me on Python 3.6.3 and Python 2.6.9... Did you try to remove all the linebreaks and the comments? they look like they're part of the pattern string...

Comment: That is weird, in 3.6.3 it's definitely having an issue.  From cmd line or are you in Ipython/Jupyter?  Not that that should matter.

Comment: Python 3 testing on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/bpEzd4) displays the same issue.

Comment: In  Python 3.6.3 I'm getting error for the linebreaks and the comments that you embedded in the pattern, once those are removed it works fine.

Comment: @alfasin: Sounds like you dropped the verbose flag.

Comment: @user2357112 no I didn't: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5rgfu6od926n51/screenshot_python_verbose_flag.png?dl=0

Comment: It looks like `re` doesn't allow whitespace inside a token even in verbose mode. Not sure whether that's a bug or a docs error.

Comment: oh if the issue is the whitespaces, then yes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Python issue 15606](https://bugs.python.org/issue15606). `re`'s behavior with whitespace inside a token in verbose mode doesn't match the documentation. You can't put whitespace in the middle of `(?=`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `?=` on the second line.
The `?` can mean multiple things like `[ ]?` which is 0 or 1 spaces which I believe is the case for the whitespace preceding it. Whitespace **is** ignored but it is making the two chars `(` and `?` into separated entities.

Move the `?=` to the 1st line and it will work. Like `(?=`

The error

```
error: nothing to repeat at position 83
```

Makes it pretty clear that `?` is here being interpreted as repetition

Comment: @BradSolomon Your issue is with whitespace.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you.  As the docs say, the whitespace should be ignored and there is no (literal) whitespace in the regex.  I would think that the lines in the verbose version would be "smushed together."

Comment: @BradSolomon Call what you want, but the `?` is not linked to the `(` unless you put them physically together. Because `?` is special and can mean multiple stuff.
The presence of whitespace is unlinking both. The whitespace is ignored but make them both separate things

Comment: But it _is_ linked.  The whitespace is ignored unless it meets one of the conditions above, neither of which it does.

Comment: @BradSolomon You can keep ignoring the issue but it is not going to be solved any other way. Good luck

Comment: I appreciate your answer and it is a working solution, just want to understand why because this isn't intuitive according to the specification from the docs.

Comment: @BradSolomon check the other answer stating incorrect behavior when compared to docs