# How to raise ValueError when AssertionError is present python?

Tags: python, regex, attributeerror, valueerror

I am working on regex and I am trying to raise a `ValueError` when a string is not found.  Here is some sample code of what I am trying to do.

```
def parse_email (s):
    import re
    re_names = re.compile ('''^regex code for pattern matching''',re.VERBOSE)

    if not re_names.match(s).group('uid'): raise ValueError

    uid = re_names.match(s).group('uid')
    domain = re_names.match(s).group('domain')
    tup = uid, domain
    return tup

parse_email('e l@gmail.com')
```

I want the `parse_email('e l@gmail.com')` function to return a `ValueError` instead I am getting an AssertionError.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Looks like you lost all your indentation when you posted.. Also, you described what you want your function to do, but never asked a question. You can refer to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you're new here to help you write a good question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think the question is now worded properly, and the indentation is fixed.

Comment: `AssertionError` exceptions can only come from assert statements. There are no assert statements in the code you've shown us, so the problem is elsewhere. It is often helpful to post the full exception traceback.

Comment: I potentially take back my previous comment. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227883/3220135) possibly your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that, when there is no successful match, the program does not get to your `raise ValueError` statement. Instead, you might check to see if there was any match at all, and if not then raise the error you want:

```
import re

def parse_email(s):
    re_names = re.compile ('''^
                           (?P<uid>[\w]+)
                           @
                           (?P<domain>[\w.-]+)?
                           $
                           ''',
                           re.VERBOSE)

    if not re_names.match(s):
        raise ValueError
    uid = re_names.match(s).group('uid')
    domain = re_names.match(s).group('domain')
    tup = uid, domain
    return tup
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up solving the problem.

```
import re

def parse_email(s):
    re_names = re.compile ('''regex stuff
                       ''',
                       re.VERBOSE)

    try:
        uid = re_names.match(s).group('uid')
        domain = re_names.match(s).group('domain')
        tup = uid, domain
        return tup
    except AssertionError:
        raise ValueError
```